# problems result nested bbcode colors

Tags: php, bbcode

I worked this period on bbcode and encountered a problem (nested similar codes)

**this is the code 01 :**

```
function FFF999_BBcode($content) 
{
    $search = array (
    '/(\[color=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/color\])/'
    );
    
    $replace = array (                   
    '<span style="color: $2">$4</span>'
    );
    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
}
```

**this is the input:**

```
[color=red][color=blue]test test test[/color][/color]
```

**this is the result 01 :**

```
<span style="color: red"><a href="page?q=color=blue">color=blue</a>test test test</span><a href="page?q=/color">/color</a><br />
```

[result code 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mHY0.png)

=====================================

Then I modified the code to this

**this is the code 02 :**

```
function FFF999_BBcode($content) 
{
    $search = array (
    '/(\[color=)(.*?)(\])/',
    '/(\/color\])/',
    );
    
    $replace = array (                   
    '<span style="color: $2">',
    '</span>',
    );
    return preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
}
```

**this is the result 02:**

```
<span style="color: red"><span style="color: blue">test test test[</span>[</span><br />
```

[result code 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OImi5.png)

=====================================

Both codes have implementation problems.

But what is the best of them programmatically to start modifying it and find a complete solution to the result?

Comment: You're still wide open to XSS like this lol `echo FFF999_BBcode('[color=red;"><img src=# onerror=javascript:alert(1)><!--]Test[/color]');` - whitelist your colours

Comment: Thank you for your response.. I have a function to protect and clean the inputs before starting to process them.. My inquiry is based on this point only

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multidimentional BBCODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69194933/multidimentional-bbcode)